# Android Tabs Bottom to Top

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

I followed a tutorial and i got the tabs i wanted but they are at the bottom of the screen.

Here is my main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Whats wrong? Thanks

Comment: Try to put the TabWidget before the FrameLayout

Comment: so much reserach with such a simple answer. thanks dude. works like a charm

Comment: added an answer for it for future generations :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the TabWidget before the FrameLayout in your XML

Comment: hey talkol. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777168/android-is-it-possible-to-create-both-bottom-and-top-tabs-on-the-screen Can you help me out on this one please? No one gave me a straight answer and its urgent for me. thanks